Make interactive icons in pdf in article
I really want in my book pdf file (article) on each page at the bottom to have interactive icons like in beamer. Namely: go to the next page, to the previous one, go to the next/previous section/subsection/subsubsection. Ideally, you need to move on to the next subsection if there is no nearest subsection. For example, after 4.8.1--4.8.2 and then 4.9.
Attached my terrible code and a screenshot of what I would like to get (only the panel at the bottom, not on the right as in the screenshot). I haven't been able to do anything all day:(
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, titlesec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia, textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref, lastpage, etoolbox, refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    % rectangle 
    \fill[blue!20] ([xshift=2cm, yshift=0.5cm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-2cm, yshift=1cm]current page.south east);
    % icons
    \ifnum\value{page}>1
        \node[align=center] at ([xshift=1cm, yshift=0.75cm]current page.south) {%
        \hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}{\tikz\fill[red] (0,0) circle (5pt);}};
    \fi
    
    \ifnum\value{page}>1
        \ifnum\value{page}<\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
            \node[align=center] at ([xshift=-1cm, yshift=0.75cm]current page.south) {%
            \hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}+1\relax}{\tikz\fill[green] (0,0) circle (5pt);}};
        \fi
    \fi
    
    \ifnum\value{page}>1
        %\ifnum\getrefnumber{section.\number\numexpr\value{section}\relax}>0
            \node[align=center] at ([xshift=-3.5cm, yshift=0.75cm]current page.south) {%
            \hyperlink{section.\number\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax}{\tikz\fill[black] (0,0) circle (5pt);}};
        %\fi
    \fi
    
    \ifnum\value{page}>1
        \node[align=center] at ([xshift=3.5cm, yshift=0.75cm]current page.south) {%
        \hyperlink{section.\number\numexpr\value{subsection}+1\relax}{\tikz\fill[white] (0,0) circle (5pt);}};
    \fi

  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Marking sections with the section number
\preto{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}>0
    \label{section.\number\value{section}}
  \fi
}

\preto{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \label{subsec:\thesection:\thesubsection}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[1-40]

\section{s2}
\lipsum[11-40]

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}

SECOND VARIANT BUT DOSNT WORK SUBSEC
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, titlesec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia, textgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref, lastpage, etoolbox, refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}>1
    \raisebox{0.75cm}{%
      \hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Previous Page}}
      \hspace{1cm}
      \hyperlink{section.\number\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Next Section}}
      \hspace{1cm}
      \hyperlink{subsec:\number\value{section}:\number\numexpr\value{subsection}+1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Next Subsection}}
    }%
  \fi
}

\preto{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}>0
    \label{section.\number\value{section}}
  \fi
}

\preto{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \label{subsec:\thesection:\thesubsection}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[1-40]

\section{s2}
\lipsum[11-40]

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}


Welcome! There's no screenshot in your question.

Please add a document class and use standard fonts if your problem can be reproduced without custom ones. More generally, please remove packages we don't need to reproduce the problem. Note that nesting tikzpictures isn't supported and is known to break.

The links work as I think they are meant to, but I'm not sure if I think they are meant to work in the way they are meant to work. The double-arrow links always point to the next/previous division, whether that be a section or a subsection.
Note that you cannot leave the link node empty or hyperref unhelpfully 'suppresses' the 'empty' link, which is most frustrating (especially if you don't realise that's why it thinks it is empty).
On the other hand, I'm also reasonably certain this is completely wrong ....
Caveat emptor
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand\nextpage{\faAngleRight}
\newcommand\prevpage{\faAngleLeft}
\newcommand\nextdiv{\faAngleDoubleRight}
\newcommand\prevdiv{\faAngleDoubleLeft}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
%% hyperref doc div 15
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/718065/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_record:nn { en }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_ref:nn { en }
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/lastpage} {.}
{
  \property_record:nn {mypage last page} {abspage,secnum}
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {.}
{
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mypage_lastpage_int { \property_ref:nn { mypage last page } { abspage } }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mypage_lastsec_int { \property_ref:nn { mypage last page } { secnum } }
}
\int_new:N \g_mypage_lastpage_int
\int_new:N \g_mypage_lastsec_int
\int_new:N \g_mypage_sec_int
\property_new:nnnn { secnum } { now } { 0 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_mypage_sec_int }}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/section/before} {.}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_mypage_sec_int
  \MakeLinkTarget{secnum}
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/subsection/before} {.}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_mypage_sec_int
  \MakeLinkTarget{secnum}
}
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \theHsecnum { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_mypage_sec_int } }
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/background} {.}
{
  \property_record:en {mypage : \int_to_arabic:n \g_shipout_readonly_int} {pagetarget}
  \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \path (0pt,0pt) -- ++(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      % rectangle 
      \fill[blue!20] (2cm,5mm) rectangle ++({\paperwidth-4cm},5mm);
      % icons
      \begin{scope}[xshift=.5\paperwidth,yshift=7.5mm,node ~ distance=7.5mm,every ~ node/.append ~ style={inner ~ sep=2.5pt}]
        \node [anchor=center] (page) at (0pt,0pt) {\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int} };
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ page] (prevpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int-1}}{pagetarget} }{\prevpage}};
        }{
          \node  [left=of ~ page] (prevpage) {%
            \phantom{\prevpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } < { \g_mypage_lastpage_int }
        {
          \node [right=of ~ page] (nextpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int+1}}{pagetarget} }{\nextpage}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ page] (nextpage)  {%
            \phantom{\nextpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_mypage_sec_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ prevpage] (prevdiv)  {%
            \hyperlink{ secnum .  \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_sec_int-1} } {\prevdiv}};
        }{
          \node  [left=of ~ prevpage] (prevdiv) {%
            \phantom{\prevdiv}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_mypage_sec_int } < { \g_mypage_lastsec_int }
        {
          \node  [right=of ~ nextpage] (nextdiv) {%
            \hyperlink{ secnum .  \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_sec_int+1} } {\nextdiv}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ nextpage] (nextdiv) {%
            \phantom{\nextdiv}};
        }
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[1-40]

\section{s2}
\lipsum[11-40]

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}

EDIT
Adding links to the first and last pages is easier because you don't need to calculate anything.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand\nextpage{\faAngleRight}
\newcommand\prevpage{\faAngleLeft}
\newcommand\nextdiv{\faAngleDoubleRight}
\newcommand\prevdiv{\faAngleDoubleLeft}
\newcommand\firstpage{\faFastBackward}
\newcommand\finalpage{\faFastForward}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
%% hyperref doc div 15
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/718065/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_record:nn { en }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_ref:nn { en }
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/lastpage} {.}
{
  \property_record:nn {mypage last page} {abspage,secnum}
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {.}
{
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mypage_lastpage_int { \property_ref:nn { mypage last page } { abspage } }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mypage_lastsec_int { \property_ref:nn { mypage last page } { secnum } }
}
\int_new:N \g_mypage_lastpage_int
\int_new:N \g_mypage_lastsec_int
\int_new:N \g_mypage_sec_int
\property_new:nnnn { secnum } { now } { 0 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_mypage_sec_int }}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/section/before} {.}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_mypage_sec_int
  \MakeLinkTarget{secnum}
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/subsection/before} {.}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_mypage_sec_int
  \MakeLinkTarget{secnum}
}
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \theHsecnum { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_mypage_sec_int } }
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/background} {.}
{
  \property_record:en {mypage : \int_to_arabic:n \g_shipout_readonly_int} {pagetarget}
  \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \path (0pt,0pt) -- ++(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      % rectangle 
      \fill[blue!20] (2cm,5mm) rectangle ++({\paperwidth-4cm},5mm);
      % icons
      \begin{scope}[xshift=.5\paperwidth,yshift=7.5mm,node ~ distance=7.5mm,every ~ node/.append ~ style={inner ~ sep=2.5pt}]
        \node [anchor=center] (page) at (0pt,0pt) {\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int} };
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ page] (prevpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int-1}}{pagetarget} }{\prevpage}};
        }{
          \node  [left=of ~ page] (prevpage) {%
            \phantom{\prevpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } < { \g_mypage_lastpage_int }
        {
          \node [right=of ~ page] (nextpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int+1}}{pagetarget} }{\nextpage}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ page] (nextpage)  {%
            \phantom{\nextpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_mypage_sec_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ prevpage] (prevdiv)  {%
            \hyperlink{ secnum .  \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_sec_int-1} } {\prevdiv}};
        }{
          \node  [left=of ~ prevpage] (prevdiv) {%
            \phantom{\prevdiv}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_mypage_sec_int } < { \g_mypage_lastsec_int }
        {
          \node  [right=of ~ nextpage] (nextdiv) {%
            \hyperlink{ secnum .  \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_sec_int+1} } {\nextdiv}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ nextpage] (nextdiv) {%
            \phantom{\nextdiv}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ prevdiv] (firstpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:1}{pagetarget} }{\firstpage}};
        }{
           \node [left=of ~ prevdiv] (firstpage) {%
             \phantom{\firstpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } < { \g_mypage_lastpage_int }
        {
          \node [right=of ~ nextdiv] (finalpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_lastpage_int}}{pagetarget} }{\finalpage}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ nextdiv] (finalpage)  {%
            \phantom{\finalpage}};
        }
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[1-40]

\section{s2}
\lipsum[11-40]

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}

As I mentioned in a comment, I only used fontawesome because I know it is compatible with all engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX etc.) and because it provides an easy source of symbols. If you have an alternative set of symbols, just substitute them in the definitions of \prevdiv etc. It is also possible to draw something with TikZ, as you did in your question, but you shouldn't nest tikzpictures and you need some text or the hyperlink gets 'suppressed'. So then you need to mess around with \phantom again.
I also used fontawesome because your screenshot used symbols and these seemed clearer to me than differently coloured dots.

I will try to tidy this up if nobody posts anything better. When they do, I'll delete my mess.

Thank you for trying to help me!
To be honest, I have not come across half of the functions that you have used. I ran the code on my computer several times and did not understand if the links were working correctly. When I click on them, it sends me to the next section and some do not change anything.

@Vitaly I tidied this up, but the links are the same. Did you compile twice? Note that I used fontawesome because I know it works with unicode engines.

Yes! This is very close to what I wanted! Thank you very much for your help. You are a God among men. I was looking for different solutions to this problem, but I couldn't solve it on my own.
Can I ask you to add a transition to the end of the book and to the first page?
Can you explain why font awesome is used?
p.s. Yes, I compiled twice
p.s.2 I don't understand how to attach a screenshot in the response and how to thank you (I don't know English well and can't figure it out on the site)

Today I will try to find out how it works and try to add something myself, but I'm not sure if it will work.
I am attaching a screenshot of how I want to give the final look to the design.

@Vitaly You're welcome. See edit. You can't add a screenshot in a comment. You can only add one into a question (or answer). But I'm not actually male ;).

Thank you very much!
Sorry, there was a confusion when translating into English, I meant a person/human
THANKS!!!

May I ask you to look at my code. I wrote in the post below about the problem that switching to a subsection does not work, although I did everything by analogy. I would like to have two solutions to the problem. Your code is fully working, but very complex. I had to work hard to understand him a little

I have one complete solution to this problem and one incomplete one (mine).
Option 1:
Switching pages and section works. But subsections throws me to the last page, no matter what I do. Although I created the code by analogy...
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, titlesec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia, textgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref, lastpage, etoolbox, refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}>1
    \raisebox{0.75cm}{%
      \hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Previous Page}} % Creating a link to the previous page by subtracting 1 from the number of this page
      \hspace{1cm}
      \hyperlink{section.\number\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Next Section}} % Creating a link to the next \section by adding 1 to the number of this \section 
      \hspace{1cm}
      \hyperlink{subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\numexpr\value{subsection}+1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Next Subsection}} % Creating a link to the next \subsection by adding 1 to the number of this \subsection 
    }%
  \fi
}

\preto{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}>0
    \label{section.\number\value{section}} % Creating a \label for each \section in the section.N format. Where N is the \section number
  \fi
}

\preto{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \label{subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\value{subsection}} % Creating a \label for each \subsection in the subsec.N.M format. Where N is the number of the \section and M is the number of the \subsection
  \fi
}



\begin{document}

\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo} 


\lipsum[1-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 
%subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\value{subsection}\\
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 



\section{s2}
\lipsum[11-40]

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\value{subsection}\\
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}


The second option (slightly modified)  from a user with the nickname sfr.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, titlesec} %управлять шрифтами. Основной, мат шрифт и прочее. titlesec - настройки заголовков разделов
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia, textgreek} % многоязычная поддержка, textgreek -греч буквы
% Значки/кнопки стрелочки 
\newcommand\nextpage{\faAngleRight} 
\newcommand\prevpage{\faAngleLeft} 
\newcommand\nextdiv{\faAngleRight\faAngleRight} 
\newcommand\prevdiv{\faAngleLeft\faAngleLeft} 
\newcommand\firstpage{\faAngleLeft\faAngleLeft\faAngleLeft} 
\newcommand\finalpage{\faAngleRight\faAngleRight\faAngleRight}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage} % настройка верхнего и нижнего колонтитулов
\pagestyle{fancy} % настройки верхнего и нижнего колонтитулов страницы
\fancyhf{} % очищает все предыдущие настройки колонтитулов
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\ExplSyntaxOn %Активация расширенного синтаксиса
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_record:nn { en } %\cs_generate_variant:Nn <имя команды> { <варианты аргументов> } -- создание новой команды
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_ref:nn { en }

%Использует хук shipout/lastpage для записи информации о последней странице (абсолютный номер страницы и номер секции).
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/lastpage} {.} 
{
  \property_record:nn {mypage last page} {abspage,secnum}
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {.}

% Использует хук begindocument/end для получения и установки значений переменных g_mypage_lastpage_int и g_mypage_lastsec_int, которые содержат информацию о последней странице и последней секции.
{
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mypage_lastpage_int { \property_ref:nn { mypage last page } { abspage } }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mypage_lastsec_int { \property_ref:nn { mypage last page } { secnum } }
}

% Объявляет новые целочисленные переменные для хранения информации о последней странице, последней секции и текущей секции.
\int_new:N \g_mypage_lastpage_int
\int_new:N \g_mypage_lastsec_int
\int_new:N \g_mypage_sec_int

% Объявляет новое свойство secnum для хранения текущего номера секции.
\property_new:nnnn { secnum } { now } { 0 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_mypage_sec_int }}

% Увеличивает значение счетчика секции перед началом каждой секции и подсекции, а затем создает метку с использованием команды \MakeLinkTarget
\hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/section/before} {.}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_mypage_sec_int
  \MakeLinkTarget{secnum}
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/subsection/before} {.}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_mypage_sec_int
  \MakeLinkTarget{secnum}
}

% Определяет команду \theHsecnum, которая возвращает номер текущей секции в арабском формате.
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \theHsecnum { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_mypage_sec_int } }

% Отрисовка элементов на страницах
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/background} {.}
{
  \property_record:en {mypage : \int_to_arabic:n \g_shipout_readonly_int} {pagetarget}
  \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \path (0pt,0pt) -- ++(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      % rectangle 
      \filldraw[fill=blue!20, draw=black] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (19.5,1.5);
      % icons
      \begin{scope}[xshift=.5\paperwidth,yshift=10mm,node ~ distance=20mm,every ~ node/.append ~ style={inner ~ sep=2.5pt}]
        \node [anchor=center] (page) at (0pt,0pt) {
            Страница \; \int_to_arabic:n  {\g_shipout_readonly_int} \; из \; \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_lastpage_int}
        };
        
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ page] (prevpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int-1}}{pagetarget} }{\prevpage}};
        }{
          \node  [left=of ~ page] (prevpage) {%
            \phantom{\prevpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } < { \g_mypage_lastpage_int }
        {
          \node [right=of ~ page] (nextpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_shipout_readonly_int+1}}{pagetarget} }{\nextpage}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ page] (nextpage)  {%
            \phantom{\nextpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_mypage_sec_int } > { 1 }
        {
          \node [left=of ~ prevpage] (prevdiv)  {%
            \hyperlink{ secnum .  \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_sec_int-1} } {\prevdiv}};
        }{
          \node  [left=of ~ prevpage] (prevdiv) {%
            \phantom{\prevdiv}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_mypage_sec_int } < { \g_mypage_lastsec_int }
        {
          \node  [right=of ~ nextpage] (nextdiv) {%
            \hyperlink{ secnum .  \int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_sec_int+1} } {\nextdiv}};
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ nextpage] (nextdiv) {%
            \phantom{\nextdiv}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } > { 1 } % Сравнивает текущий номер страницы с номером последней страницы. Если текущая страница меньше последней страницы, то выполняется блок true
        {
          \node [left=of ~ prevdiv] (firstpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:1}{pagetarget} }{\firstpage}};
        }{
           \node [left=of ~ prevdiv] (firstpage) {%
             \phantom{\firstpage}};
        }
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \g_shipout_readonly_int } < { \g_mypage_lastpage_int } 
        {
          \node [right=of ~ nextdiv] (finalpage) {%
            \hyperlink{\property_ref:en { mypage:\int_to_arabic:n {\g_mypage_lastpage_int}}{pagetarget} }{\finalpage}}; %Если условие выполняется, создается гиперссылка на последнюю страницу, используя значок finalpage
        }{
          \node [right=of ~ nextdiv] (finalpage)  {%
            \phantom{\finalpage}}; %Если условие не выполняется, создается пустое место (\phantom{\finalpage}) вместо кнопки.
        }
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff % Отключение расширенного синтаксиса:

\begin{document}
\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}

\section{s2}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsubsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}


